# Load CSV from Blob to Azure SQL Server - Referenced external data source not found

Tags: sql-server, csv, azure, sqlbulkcopy, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to bulk insert a CSV hosted in blob storage into Azure SQL Server, as is described in [this MSDN post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/02/23/loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-azure-sql-database/).

My code is taken almost entirely from [this Microsoft Github sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/features/sql-bulk-load/load-from-azure-blob-storage/LoadFromAzureBlobStorage.sql).

When running it I receive the following error:

> Referenced external data source "MyAzureBlobStorage" not found.

```
-- Create Database Master Key
IF (select Count(*) from sys.symmetric_keys where name like '%DatabaseMasterKey%') = 0
BEGIN
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MYPASSWORD'; 
END

-- Create Storage Credential
IF (select Count(*) from sys.database_credentials where name = 'MyAzureBlobStorageCredential') = 0
BEGIN
print 'Creating credential'
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyAzureBlobStorageCredential
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = '<secret>';
END

-- Create External Data Source
IF (select Count(*) from sys.external_data_sources where name = 'MyAzureBlobStorage') = 0
BEGIN
print 'creating external data source'
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/upload',
    CREDENTIAL= MyAzureBlobStorageCredential);
END

-- Create temp table to hold data
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#mytemptable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #mytemptable
CREATE TABLE #mytemptable(
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
    -- etc
)

-- Bulk insert into temp table
BULK INSERT #mytemptable
FROM 'mycsv.csv'
WITH ( DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage',
        FORMAT='CSV', CODEPAGE = 65001, --UTF-8 encoding
        FIRSTROW=2,
        TABLOCK);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. I found the answer in the comments by @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, pasting it here to make it more visible:

> I repro'd, and BULK INSERT currently doesn't work against temp tables. Create a permanent table and try.

Comment: Currently: Temp tables are actually supported on Azure SQL, so weird they are not supported on latest SQL 2017 (14.0.3008.27)

Answer (score 4):

Here's another sample.  Note that the secret is the "SAS token" copied from the azure portal without the leading '?'

[image]

```
drop DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyAzureBlobStorageCredential
drop  EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage

go
-- Create Storage Credential
print 'Creating credential'
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyAzureBlobStorageCredential
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=2016-05-31&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2017-05-08T23:03:46Z&st=2017-05-08T15:03:46Z&spr=https&sig=nxxxUJXfp%2BL23%2FULs2wY3%2BYAdFewzNsqp73rcsSoge4%3D';

-- Create External Data Source
--full url https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/files/tran.csv
print 'creating external data source'
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/files',
    CREDENTIAL= MyAzureBlobStorageCredential);

--test
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK  'tran.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage',
   SINGLE_CLOB) AS DataFile;
```

David

Comment: Somebody edited my post and took out my (sanitized) secret, but I am using the SAS without the ?. So the `OPENROWSET` query works, but I still get the same error if I then try to execute a `BULK INSERT` into a temp table. Could you see if executing a `BULK INSERT` into a temp table works on your end?

Comment: I repro'd, and BULK INSERT currently doesn't work against temp tables.  Create a permanent table and try.

And if you get this error:
"Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)""

try specifying

ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',

Comment: I'm trying against a permanent table and sure enough I'm getting the `Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"` error. I tried the row terminator option but it doesn't help. How did you debug that error to know what option to try?

Comment: Apparently that error can mean any sort of mismatch between your file and the expected format.  I ran through the sample here:https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/features/sql-bulk-load/load-from-azure-blob-storage  You should try with those files to isolate the difference.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Do you happen to know why BULK INSERT does not work against temp tables?

Comment: David,

I tried using the twitter handle @DavidBrowne-Microsoft but this didn't work from my Titter Account.  I'm making a new post with the same question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269147/microsoft-tech-references-for-bulk-insert-may-have-some-gaps-cant-get-them.

I could use some input.  I realize that cutting edge technology always is many months ahead of correct documentation. :)  No problem with that, I just need a working answer.