# Microsoft tech references for BULK INSERT may have some gaps ... can't get them to work

Tags: sql-server, csv, azure

Huge edit -- I removed the ';' characters and replace them with 'GO' and ... the secondary key and URL worked, except I got this:
Cannot bulk load. The file "06May2013_usr_tmp_cinmachI.csv" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.

BTW, this can't be true :) -- I'm able to use PowerShell to upload the file so I'm sure it's not my account credentials.  Here is the code I'm using now, again, it WON'T fit into a {} block no matter what I do with this editor, sorry for the inconvenience.

The docs can CREATE MASTER KEY is used to encrypt SECRET later on but there's no obvious link, assumed this is all under the hood -- is that right?  If not, maybe that's what's causing my access error.

So, the issue with the data source not existing was errant syntax -- one can't use ';' evidently to terminate blocks of SQL but 'GO' will work.

The CSV file does exist:

[image: Azure Blob Blade]

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'S0me!nfo'
GO
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL AzureStorageCredential
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'removed'
GO
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE myDataSource
WITH (TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE, LOCATION = 'https://dtstestcsv.blob.core.windows.net/sunsource', CREDENTIAL = AzureStorageCredential)
GO
BULK
INSERT dbo.ISSIVISFlatFile
FROM '06May2013_usr_tmp_cinmachI.csv'
WITH
(DATA_SOURCE = 'myDataSource', FORMAT = 'CSV')
```

Comment: So at this stage are you loading into a non-temp table? You are missing something very important in your question, and that is _the error message_.

Comment: Sorry, my excuse is just as lame as the original error.  :)

Comment: I tried exactly the same thing today and got an identical error. So I gave up and used the Azure Data Factory Copy button which worked perfectly.

Comment: That does not sound very good.  I had a support instance in to Azure Team and they didn't even bother calling back.  Not a real confidence builder but I'll look at what you just did.  I'd rather not have to do this each week.

Comment: Actually after a couple of days banging my head on Data Factory I'm ready to come back to this

Comment: I'm about ready to invest some time in Data Factory.  Are you saying it doesn't work?

Comment: Update ... I see what you might mean.  I get up to loading a CSV file.  The field delimiter is a comma, row terminator is \n.  This is all set correctly.  The data can't be previewed so when I click 'Next' at that step, nothing works and it just says 'The schema can't be detected' or some such.  To top it off, you can't reset the wizard.  If the screen is refreshed, it takes you all the way back to the start page.  Wow ...

Comment: It's "immature" and I'm really having difficulties understanding the timeslice/scheduling aspects,as in: I have a file and a pipeline all set up but it took me a long time to work out how to get it to import it. I didn't have any problems actually identifying the schema though. I think I'll push through with it now though.

Comment: Here's one that might snag you if you don't watch it.  The PowerShell script I found copies a file up to a BLOB.  Then copies it back down so a new user of PS can verify they're success.

Make sure not to be lazy and just overwrite with what Azure is sending back down.  It can (but not always) somehow give you a blank file.

Solved that by having the script create a new \ConfirmUpload\ folder in the Destination path and put the downloaded file from the BLOB there.

This makes sure the file uploaded doesn't get corrupted.

With this done my import will work.

Comment: That can be stated better -- when downloading an uploaded file to verify the upload happened correctly, force the download into a new folder.

I was being lazy, thinking that for a test I didn't care if the download over wrote the first file.  Well, it creates issues and is bad practice anyhow.  And you'll really be scratching your head wondering why the data factory doesn't work since it's not obvious the upload is now corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

I feel obliged to post at some info even if it's not a full answer.

I was getting this error:

> > Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 58
> >     Cannot bulk load. The file "container/folder/file.txt" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.

I believe the problem might have been that I generated my SAS key *from* right now, but that is UTC time, meaning that here in Australia, the key only becomes valid in ten hours. So I generated a new key that started a month before and it worked.

The SAS (Shared Access Signature) is a big string that is created as follows:

1. In Azure portal, go to your storage account
2. Press Shared Access Signature
3. Fill in fields (make sure your start date is a few days prior, and you can leave *Allowed IP addresses* blank)
4. Press *Generate SAS*
5. Copy the string in the *SAS Token* field
6. *Remove* the leading `?` before pasting it into your SQL script

Below is my full script with comments.

```
-- Target staging table
IF object_id('recycle.SampleFile') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE recycle.SampleFile
    (
    Col1 VARCHAR(MAX)
    );


-- more info here
-- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2017/02/23/loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-azure-sql-database/

-- You can use this to conditionally create the master key
select * from sys.symmetric_keys where name like '%DatabaseMasterKey%'


-- Run once to create a database master key
-- Can't create credentials until a master key has been generated
-- Here, zzz is a password that you make up and store for later use
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'zzz';




-- Create a database credential object that can be reused for external access to Azure Blob
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL BlobTestAccount 
WITH 
-- Must be SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE to access blob storage
IDENTITY= 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
-- Generated from Shared Access Signature area in Storage account
-- Make sure the start date is at least a few days before
-- otherwise UTC can mess you up because it might not be valid yet
-- Don't include the ? or the endpoint. It starts with 'sv=', NOT '?' or 'https'
SECRET = 'sv=2016-05-31&zzzzzzzzzzzz'


-- Create the external data source
-- Note location starts with https. I've seen examples without this but that doesn't work
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE BlobTest
WITH ( 
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE, 
    LOCATION = 'https://yourstorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net',
    CREDENTIAL= BlobTestAccount);



BULK INSERT recycle.SampleFile
FROM 'container/folder/file'
WITH ( DATA_SOURCE = 'BlobTest');




-- If you're fancy you can use these to work out if your things exist first
select * from sys.database_scoped_credentials
select * from sys.external_data_sources

DROP EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE BlobTest;
DROP DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL BlobTestAccount;
```

One thing that this *wont* do that ADF does, is pick up a file based on wildcard.

That is: If I have a file called `ABC_20170501_003.TXT`, I need to explicitly list that in the `bulk insert` load script, whereas in ADF I can just specify `ABC_20170501` and it automatically wildcards the rest

Unfortunately there is no (easy) way to enumerate files in blob storage from SQL Server. I eventually got around this by using Azure Automation to run a powershell script to enumerate the files and register them into a table that SQL Server could see. This seems complicated but actually Azure Automation is a very useful tool to learn and use, and it works very reliably

More opinions on ADF:

I couldn't find a way to pass the filename that I loaded (or other info) into the database.

Do not use ADF if you need data to be loaded in the order it appears in the file (i.e. as captured by an identity field). ADF will try and do things in parallel. In fact, my ADF did insert things in order for about a week (i.e. as recorded by the identity) then one day it just started inserting stuff out of order.

The timeslice concept is useful in limited circumstances (when you have cleanly delineated data in cleanly delineated files that you want to drop neatly into a table). In any other circumstances it is complicated, unwieldy and difficult to understand and use. In my experience real world data needs more complicated rules to work out and apply the correct merge keys.

I don't know the cost difference between importing files via ADF and files via BULK INSERT, but ADF is slow. I don't have to patience to hack through Azure blades to find metrics right now but your talking 5 minutes in ADF vs 5 seconds in Bulk Insert

## UPDATE:

Try Azure Data Factory V2. It is *vastly* improved, and you are no longer bound to timeslices.