# SQL Server 2016 errror Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL'

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-virtual-machine, external-tables, external-data-source

I have two SQL Server 2016 VMs in Azure. I am trying to connect these two sql server instances using External datasource. I can safely connect the two instances from my local pc, remotely.

While querying using external table/data source, I am getting this:

[image]

Kindly note

1. I have used both RDBMS/SHARD_MAP_Manager
2. Credential is valid credential
3. I know I can use Linked Servers, but I don't want it. As I am planning to move these databases to SQL Azure. External table and datasource is not mandatory. You can suggest alternatives other than linked servers.

I need a query or part of query that will work with both, SQL Server (virtual / physical server) and SQL Azure (Database as a Service)

Comment: Is it erroring on the DROP or the CREATE? Please indicate which line the error occurs on. Are you certain sharding works with VM's? All examples I see are for Azure DB

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql says: _Use SHARD_MAP_MANAGER when creating an external data source for Elastic Database query for sharding on Azure SQL Database_ - it seems sharding is only for Azure SQL DB, Not VM's

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I tried RDBMS too.. Even my Drop DataSource statement inside` if` giving same error.

Comment: What's the compatability level?

Comment: master 130
tempdb 130
model 130
msdb 130
TestDb 130

Comment: Mine too. Here's a script that works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269147/microsoft-tech-references-for-bulk-insert-may-have-some-gaps-cant-get-them/45452574#45452574. I suggest you copy paste the entire script rather than just screenshotting it. Then you might discover the issue

Comment: Mine also highlights exactly the same way: `CREATE EXTERNAL DATA` is one colour and `SOURCE` is a different colour

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: No. We dropped the migration plan and went with old VM based sql server.